# How to apply even-odd row css to dynamically loaded components?

Tags: css, angular, angular-components

I am working on solution.

I have applied even/odd row css using :Even,:odd selector on specific class of elemets

I have two tables first one having initially loaded data with expand button on click of which i load dynamic table after that specific row

my css code on first table is working fine but not for second

Here is html that i have copied from inspect element functionality of google chrome web inspector

```
<div class="report-table-container" style="margin-top: 30px;">
<div class="row report-row">
    <div class="col-4" style="padding-left: 5px;">
        <button class="btn btn-sm">-</button>USA
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">8.26M</div>
    <div class="col-1">534.00</div>
    <div class="col-1">2.83K</div>
    <div class="col-1">317.81M</div>
    <div class="col-1">8.26M</div>
    <div class="col-1">695.00</div>
</div>
    // second level table 
    <dynamic-component>
        <div class="row report-row">
                <div class="col-4" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" style="padding-left: 40px;">iOS</div>
                <div class="col-1">5.15M</div>
                <div class="col-1">392.00</div>
                <div class="col-1">2.15K</div>
                <div class="col-1">183.98M</div>
                <div class="col-1">5.15M</div>
                <div class="col-1">490.00</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row report-row">
                <div class="col-4" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" style="padding-left: 40px;">Android</div>
                <div class="col-1">3.11M</div>
                <div class="col-1">142.00</div>
                <div class="col-1">683.35</div>
                <div class="col-1">133.82M</div>
                <div class="col-1">3.11M</div>
                <div class="col-1">205.00</div>
        </div>
    </dynamic-component>
```

CSS code for applying odd/even styles on all rows containing ".report-row" class

```
div.report-row:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
div.report-row:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

The problem occurs due to dynamic-component tag if i remove that its working fine.

Here are the screenshots
[image]

[image]
Please help

Please help

Comment: Can you share your angular template code instead of the generated code from the browser ?

Answer (score 1):

Add `dynamic-component` like this:

```
 dynamic-component div.report-row:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

dynamic-component div.report-row:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: if you see my parent row is out side dynamic component
my css is working fine but what ever rows in dynamic component css detects first row as odd row because of dynamic component tag
This solution is not working for me
Already tried this one

Answer (score 0):

The issue is occurring because of `<dynamic-component>` tag. Better you generate the dynamic component by using `ng-container' where you are generating the dynamic component.

You did not share the complete code so its hard to tell the exact fix. If you can replicate your issue in stackblitz, would be easier give the exact fix.

Comment: Already generated using ng-container.
that's not issue for sure problem injected component always consider child table's first row as odd irrespective of parent row is odd or not

Comment: is it possible to load dynamic component without selector tag?
if that is possible. my solution will automatically work

Comment: Yes, its possible. Please refer this  official link -  https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader